# How to fix Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI. error in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, installation

I'm migrating from Android Studio to IntellijIdea and after configuring it and finally getting the project to work, I'm faced with this issue where I can't install my app.

IJ gives me this error:

[image]

I've visited a similar issue but nothing helpful there.

Comment: Does it help if you disable Instant Run ("Settings | Build... | Instant Run") ?

Comment: oh I found the answer.I added -t flag and it installed fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it for anyone facing the same issue.Add this as a flag to your adb `-t`